# count of 5 consecutive empty lines after comma

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

```
day:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
ab1:,P,,P,,,,,,,,,P,P,P,,,,P,P,P,P,,,P,P,P,,P,,

ab2:P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,,

ab3:,,,P,,,,,,,,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,P,,,,,,,,,
```

continuous blank count greater than 5 then print count of continuous blank
result:

```
ab1:8

ab2:0

ab3:7,8
```

and between dates from 4th day to 12th for ab3:
 output:ab3:7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='ab[0-9]+:|,{5,}' 'NR>1 && NF{ 
           r=""; 
           for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { 
               len=length($i)-1; if(len >= 5) r=(r!="")? r","len : len 
           } 
           printf("%s%s\n", $1, (r!="")? r : 0) 
       }' file
```

The output:

```
ab1:8
ab2:0
ab3:7,8
```

---

*Details*:

- `-v FPAT='ab[0-9]+:|,{5,}'` - pattern defining field value
- `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through the fields which are a sequences of commas
- `len=length($i)-1` - count commas followed by "empty" space
- `r=(r!="")? r","len : len` - accumulating counting results

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61929/discussion-on-answer-by-romanperekhrest-count-of-5-consecutive-empty-lines-after).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '/^ab/ and print /^(ab\d+:)/, /P,{6,}/ ? join ",", map tr/,//d-1, //g : 0' data

Output:-
ab1:8
ab2:0
ab3:7,8
```

Will look at lines that begin with ab only

`map` will apply the transformation on fields which see a P followed by more than 5 commas. What map does is counts the commas less 1 and passes them on to join.

Comment: one more help if i want count from between dates from 4th day to 12th output:ab3:7